# cannot get mod_wsgi working for https but it works for http. 'Client denied by server configuration'

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a web application using Django and I am trying to use mod_wsgi to run my web server over https.

The following command generates configuration that works and allows me to connect via port 80.

> sudo python3.6 manage.py runmodwsgi --setup-only --port=80 --user
>   apache --group apache --server-root=/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80

However when I use following command I am getting a client denied by server configuration error. I get this error whether I try to access it from the same host or external.

> sudo python3.6 manage.py runmodwsgi --setup-only --user=apache
>   --group=apache --server-root=/etc/mod_wsgi-express-443 --https-only --https-port=443 --ssl-certificate-file=/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt  --ssl-certificate-key-file=/etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key  --server-name=myhost.local

From web browser

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /login/ on this server.

in the error_log

> Wed Apr 11 18:47:33.429059 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 12053:tid
>   140251110680704] AH00489: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/4.6.4
>   Python/3.6 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips configured -- resuming normal
>   operations [Wed Apr 11 18:47:33.429098 2018] [core:notice] [pid
>   12053:tid 140251110680704] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd
>   (mod_wsgi-express) -f /etc/mod_wsgi-express-443/httpd.conf -D
>   MOD_WSGI_VIRTUAL_HOST -D MOD_WSGI_WITH_HTTPS -D MOD_WSGI_HTTPS_ONLY -D
>   MOD_WSGI_MPM_ENABLE_EVENT_MODULE -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_EVENT_MODULE
>   -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_WORKER_MODULE -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_PREFORK_MODULE' [Wed Apr 11 18:47:50.725314 2018]
>   [authz_core:error] [pid 12061:tid 140251110143744] [client
>   10.16.18.11:63623] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /etc/mod_wsgi-express-443/htdocs/

many thanks.

Comment: Dealt with on the mod_wsgi mailing list. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/bqD8lDPL9lQ Simple answer is that ``--server-name`` must be a valid hostname the same as used in the URL for the site. Cannot use ``localhost``, or an IP address.